# How to find specific host/service on the internet

Tags: networking, dns, iot, p2p

I am trying to figure out how to find the ip address of a specific machine/service on the internet.

A little background.

I am building a smart doorbell. It is made from a doorbell, connected to a hub. The hub implements various "advanced" features. Both ( the doorbell and the hub ) are on the same lan, so they can discover each other through Zeroconf/mDNS.

Now, what I want is the ability to view the doorbell video stream, send/receive voice, and command the door opening from a smartphone app, even when my smartphone is "on the road", connected through the mobile network or 3rd party wifi networks.

The problem is how to find the hub? I cannot user Zeroconf, because it is made for local networks. Is DNS the only way? In which case I should setup a no-ip ( or other similar service ) account.

I have seen that commercial cameras and other IoT devices "talk" to the manufacturers servers, which act as relays. But I want a decentralized, spy-free solution ( I don't trust them ).

Is DNS the only way to discover the hub ip? Obviously I'll need to setup the NAT to let in incoming connections ( UPnP maybe!?! ). But this is another story.

What are your suggestions?

p.s. is IPFS a possible solution? maybe I could publish the hub ip on IPFS

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you need a server at least to find other peers, a similar solution for decentralized downloading is DHT, it works like below.

1. DHT bootstrap : connect to pulic server to get the infomation of other peers
2. DHT find : using the information to find other peers
3. Peer Connection : connect to peers and change infomation

As you mension NAT and Upnp, you can first check if Nat-Pmp or Upnp works in your device, if not, maybe you need to use ICE.